# Bootstrap dropdown - right side of the list gets cut off on Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, drop-down-menu

When I tried to implement some dropdown lists with Bootstrap on a webpage, I noticed that one of them gets cut off on the right side, which looks like this:

[image: a busy cat]

I am testing with Firefox. Firebug doesn't show any conflict with an `overflow` attribute, but funnily enough when I de- and reactivate the `width` attribute of the menu's parent container, the line finally appears, but bold though. I tested the page with IE, where the menu looked fine. Is this just a flaw of Firefox, and can this be fixed somehow? I know this is just a minor cosmetic issue, but it looks really awful in my eyes...

Here's some of my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
...     
<div class="para">
    ...
    <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form data">
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            ...
            <div class="row">
                ...
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <select name="unit" size="1" class="form-control unit" required>
                        <option value="kW">kW</option>
                        <option value="MW">MW</option>
                        <option value="GW">GW</option>
                        <option value="kWh">kWh</option>
                        <option value="MWh">MWh</option>
                        <option value="GWh">GWh</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue will solve if you wrap your select field by a div element which width 98% like :

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div style="width:98%">
    <select name="unit" size="1" class="form-control unit" required>
        <option value="kW">kW</option>
        <option value="MW">MW</option>
        <option value="GW">GW</option>
        <option value="kWh">kWh</option>
        <option value="MWh">MWh</option>
        <option value="GWh">GWh</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also gave the select tag a width of 98%, the line is there finally! Thanks for giving me the hint.