# Bootswatch dropdown - last character of the list cut off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, bootswatch

The last character of the dropdown list keeps getting cut off when applying a bootswatch theme. The dropdown HTML is

```
<div class='menu' id="dropmenu">
  <select name="dates" method="GET" action="/" width="300px" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected">{{dropset}}</option>
    {% for date in dates %}
      <option value="{{date}}">{{date}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

The result is

[image]

The closest solution is [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874643/bootstrap-dropdown-right-side-of-the-list-gets-cut-off-on-firefox) but isn't working for me. Tried css text align, various widths (px & %), etc but still no luck. It does **not** get cut off when using bootstrap but it's hard to say this is a bootswatch issue given it's popularity. Any ideas??

**EDIT**: It appears to be theme related. Originally I was using Flatly but when I tried Cerulean, Cyborg, Darkly & United it's not cut off. Cosmo cuts off too though... strange

Comment: could it be because width is in px? ( width="300px" ) . Have you tried %

Answer (score 0):

try this make ( width:100% )

```html
<div class='menu' id="dropmenu" >
  <select name="dates" method="GET" action="/" width="100%" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected">{{dropset}}</option>
    {% for date in dates %}
      <option value="{{date}}">{{date}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  </div>
```